# Copy a string splitted to another string

Tags: java, string, syntax

In some place of a class **I have declared a temporal String variable**:

```
String name;
```

Which I will use to **store data from a text**. The text have many **fields with these two types of format**:

```
Type: text/html

name=foo
```

For this case, I am particularly interested in the fields **of the type** `name=foo`

So, **I breaked previously the lines of the text** using `split`

```
String lines[] = text.split("\n");
```

And, again, I will use `split` to identify the fields of the type mentioned. In the code below, the while cycle stops where it detects a `name=foo` field, and prints the value of that field in the console.

```
int i = 0;  // Counter for the while cycle

while (!(lines[i].split("=")[0].equals("name"))) {
    i++;                      

    if (lines[i].split("=")[0].equals("name")) // If the field is name...
    System.out.println(lines[i].split("=")[1]); // Prints the value of the field

    name = lines[i].split("=")[1]; // <-- My problem is here
}
```

My problem starts when I want to **copy the value of the field to the String variable mentioned early**, giving me an *java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException*.

I need that String to do something with it later. Any idea to **safely copy the value of that field to a String variable**?

Comment: are you sure that all of your lines[] contain data of type "xxxx=xxxxx" ?

Comment: you should show the class type of "name".

Comment: @SaraSeppola The text may contain data of both types "XXX:XXX" and "XXX=XXX".

Comment: Well then, if it has a `:` instead of a `=`, the resulting array doesn't have a `1` index ... and you receive the (correct) error you show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding paranthesis to your if saves you from two problems:

- if a line contains no = the whole String is in [0] and accessing [1] will result in said Exception
- you are changing (overwriting) the variable name regardless of the condition

To please the compiler you may also want to intialize name to something like `null`.

```
int i = 0;  // Counter for the while cycle

while (!(lines[i].split("=")[0].equals("name"))) {
    i++;                      

    if (lines[i].split("=")[0].equals("name")){ // If the field is name...
        System.out.println(lines[i].split("=")[1]); // Prints the value of the field

        name = lines[i].split("=")[1]; // <-- My problem is here
    }
}
```

Comment: Who upvotes this? It's completely incorrect and has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @BrianRoach while I agree, that you should always check for the number of elements (as `"name".split("=")`would otherwise be troublesome) this is a step towards a solution

Comment: After checking, this solves the problem in general. A little observation when I was obtaining the strings is I had not just the string, but along with them the break lines, so to remove them I used a solution of the type `name.replaceAll("[\n\r]", "");`.

Comment: Turned in my [own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23231648/1266906) with bounds-checking. While probably not neccessary in this specific case, it often saves headaches and hotfixes ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
String name;
name = lines[i].split("=")[1];
```

Here name will overwrite every time.

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
String names[];

String lines[] = text.split("\n");
names[] = new String[lines.length];
```

And inside you while loop do it like:

```
names[i] = lines[i].split("=")[1];
```

Comment: While this is a good tip if the OP wants to preserve all the names outside of the loop, it doesn't answer the question / solve the problem. The issue comes out in the comments; they have two different formats.

Comment: I completely agreed. This is just a suggestion because the value of name will always overwritten, hence makes no sense to assign the value into name variable.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few things to note about your code:

- you probably miss `{}` after the `if`-statement and therefore update name every run of the `while`-loop
- you access `[1]` without checking how many elements the `split("=")` yielded
- you literally call `split("=")` 4 times on almost every line. Save CPU-time by introducing a temporary variable!
- you can replace your `while`-loop by a `for`-loop which also finds `name=value` in the first line and does not "throw up" if `name=value` is not inside any of the lines (you don't check whether `i` is less than `lines.length`)

I left your comments inside my answer; feel free to remove them.

Variant a (using an index):

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    // Only split once and keep X=Y together in name=X=Y by specifying , 2
    final String[] split = lines[i].split("=", 2);

    if (split.length == 2 && split[0].equals("name")){ // If the field is name...
        System.out.println(split[1]); // Prints the value of the field

        name = split[1]; // <-- My problem is here
        break; // no need to look any further
    }
}
```

Variant b (using "for-each"):

```
for (String line : lines) {
    // Only split once and keep X=Y together in name=X=Y by specifying , 2
    final String[] split = line.split("=", 2);

    if (split.length == 2 && split[0].equals("name")) { // If the field is name...
        System.out.println(split[1]); // Prints the value of the field

        name = split[1]; // <-- My problem is here
        break; // no need to look any further
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your problem is when you reach the last line or a line which doesn't contains a "=" sign. You are checking

```
!(lines[i].split("=")[0].equals("name"))
```

but then you add 1 to i, so maybe this condition now is false

```
if (lines[i].split("=")[0].equals("name"))
```

and you will get java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException here

```
name = lines[i].split("=")[1];
```

if the line doesn't contains a "=".

Try

```
if (lines[i].split("=")[0].equals("name")) { // If the field is name...
    System.out.println(lines[i].split("=")[1]); // Prints the value of the field

    name = lines[i].split("=")[1];
}
```